# how to match 2 criteria in macro

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have the following codes that look up the column for Columbus. But how do I specify that I only want to look up the column for Columbus in Ohio by also referring to row 4 (State)?

```
Amount = WorksheetFunction.Match("Columbus", Rows("5:5"), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Looping thru all the records -

```
Dim Amount As Variant
Dim lngRow as long
lngRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lngRow 'Considering row 1 has headers
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5) = "Columbus" And ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4) = "Ohio" Then
        Amount = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Variant Arrays and cycle through that it will be quicker:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet
    Dim rngArr() As Variant
    rngArr = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(rngArr, 2)

        If rngArr(1, i) = "Ohio" And rngArr(2, i) = "Columbus" Then Exit For
    Next i

    If i <= UBound(rngArr, 2) Then
        Dim Amount As Long
        Amount = i
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Found"
    End If
End With
```